# Multipart Form Data Input Java Model Attribute is not injecting the element's in Request Class - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm try to upload file along with some form inputs, I have created a Spring Boot POST Controller. Having @ModelAttribue as an input class, at application logging it is visible that in getting the byte stream at application level. Issue here is the @ModelAttribute is not setting those those in Java Pojo class. It's getting null. Below is my Controller Method and Request payload class and logs.

What I'm doing wrong here.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/registration/file", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public BaseResponse fileTest(@ModelAttribute("data") FileUpload fileUpload) {
    log.info("..........getEmail:{}", fileUpload.getEmail());
    log.info("..........getCrDoc:{}", fileUpload.getCrDoc());
    return new BaseResponse();
}

@Data
public class FileUpload {
    private String email;

    private MultipartFile crDoc;
}
```

**-- LOG's**

```
HttpLoggingFilter:96 | Request - [PATH INFO:/pvt/registration/file] [REQUEST PARAMETERS:{}] [REQUEST BODY:------WebKitFormBoundaryDn9gdoWJ3qb48OObContent-Disposition: form-data; name="email"hello@abc.com------WebKitFormBoundaryDn9gdoWJ3qb48OObContent-Disposition: form-data; name="crDoc"; filename="sample.png"Content-Type: image/png�PNGIHDR
PrivateUserRegistrationController:61 | ..........getEmail:null
PrivateUserRegistrationController:62 | ..........getCrDoc:null
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should update @ModelAttribute("data") to @ModelAttribute then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, by adding below bean. It is working now.

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() throws IOException {    
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(appConstants.multipartUploadFileMaxSize);
    multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(appConstants.multipartUploadFileMaxSize);
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(appConstants.multipartUploadFileMaxSize);
    multipartResolver.setUploadTempDir(
            new DefaultResourceLoader().getResource(String.format("file:%s", appConstants.fileTempPathUploads)));
    multipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return multipartResolver;
}
```